# How to upload file to amazon s3 using MAMP?

Tags: php, apache, file, mamp

I'm trying to push a file to a Amazon s3 filebucket.

I'm posting the file through an html form.

I try to generate a path to the file like this($file is a part of a foreach, because i need to support multiple files in a form-submit.)

```
$file['tmp_name'].'/'.$file['name'];
```

this outputs a filepath like this

```
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpZDcVQv/pdf.pdf
```

/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/ exists, but nothing is inside it. I have set access read and write for everyone to that folder.

I use a library to post the images to Amazon: https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class It also complains that the filepath i have provided doesn't exist. It's running a check like:

```
if (!file_exists($file) || !is_file($file) || !is_readable($file))
```

How come the files aren't added?
Am I referencing the wrong folder? The file with the code is in /web/projectname/
Someone on the internet said something unclear about php removing the temp-file directly. Is this after the response has been run? Do I need to address this in some way?

The most simple code that generates the problem:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    $filepath = $file['tmp_name'].'/'.$file['name'];
    if(file_exists($filepath)){
        echo 'true <br />';
    }else{
        echo 'false <br />';
    }

}
```

This echo:es false even if files have been uploaded.

$filepath contains the path i described above.

Comment: we need the code that processes the HTML form, and specifically the file upload.

Comment: have you read [the manual on processing uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)?

Answer (score 0):

as [the manual states](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`
>   The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server.

and

> `$_FILES['userfile']['name']`
>   The original name of the file on the client machine.

this means that `file_exists($file['tmp_name'])` should be `true`.

The path `$file['tmp_name'].'/'.$file['name']` is bogus, since `$file['name']` is there only for informing you of the original name, but this name is not used while saving the uploaded file on the server.

So in your example `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpZDcVQv` is actually the uploaded file.